# Visual Composer root shortcode container

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I try to add a custom shortcode to visual composer in their editor with the function [vc_map](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524332).
I succeed to create a [shortcode container](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524362) but shortcode container are always in a "Row" element.

What is the way to create a root shortcode container to avoid an unnecessary html structure ?

Comment: Visual composer do not allow to add any block without row and column

Comment: can you show your code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

`“Row“` is the main content element of Visual Composer. Rows are used to divide your page into the logic blocks with columns, columns later will hold your content blocks. Rows can be divided into the layouts `(eg. 1/2 + 1/2, 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3, and so on)`. Your page can have unlimited number of rows.   To change row's position, click and drag row's drag handler (top left row's corner) and drag row around (vertical axis).

**Row stretch**:-
Select stretching options for row and content (Note: stretched may not work properly if parent container has `"overflow: hidden"` CSS property).

[Visual composer Content Elements](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/VC/pages/524364/Content+Elements#ContentElements-Row)